# Tensorflow import failed - SystemError: initialization of _message raised unreported exception

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am currently running Anaconda 1.9.2 on Ubuntu 18.04. I updated to the Anaconda 1.9.2 version and since then I am facing problems to import tensorflow, pandas, sklearn etc. I get the following error message when I'm trying to import.

```
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
**>>> import tensorflow**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 40, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.internal import api_implementation
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/api_implementation.py", line 154, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
SystemError: initialization of _message raised unreported exception
```

```
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 49, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 66, in <module>
    from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame, _shared_docs
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 102, in <module>
    class NDFrame(PandasObject, SelectionMixin):
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2133, in NDFrame
    protocol=pkl.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL):
AttributeError: module 'pickle' has no attribute 'HIGHEST_PROTOCOL'


>>> import numpy
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ..utils._joblib import Memory
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_joblib.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..externals.joblib import __all__   # noqa
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py", line 112, in <module>
    from .memory import Memory, MemorizedResult, register_store_backend
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/memory.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import hashing
  File "/home/deepak/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/hashing.py", line 22, in <module>
    Pickler = pickle._Pickler
AttributeError: module 'pickle' has no attribute '_Pickler'
```

Comment: I have properly marked the error message as code block with <!-- language: lang-none -->. This makes it more readable. Please add some deatails of error circumsatnces.

Comment: Please add more detail about this error!

Comment: I have edited the question. What more details should I provide?